# Getting W/Activity: Can request only one set of permissions at a time

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions, android-gps

I made an app that have a request for camera and GPS, but when I execute I am getting this warning several times with less than 1 second of each other.

> W/Activity: Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time)

Can some one tell me why?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mStatusCamera = intent.getStringExtra("camera");
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this) {

        @Override
        protected IViewFinder createViewFinderView(Context context) {
            return new CustomZXingScannerView(context);
        }

    };
    List<BarcodeFormat> formats = new ArrayList<>();
    mListaPassageiros = new ArrayList<>();
    formats.add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
    setContentView(mScannerView);
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!checkPermission()) {
            requestPermission();
        } else {
            executarDepoisDaPermissao();
        }
    }
}
private boolean checkPermission() {
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

public void executarDepoisDaPermissao() {
    final BancoController crud = new BancoController(getBaseContext());
    mConectado = isNetworkAvailable();
}
```

Added RequestPermissio as requested.

```
 private void requestPermission() {
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!checkPermission()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

}
```

Can I use it that way?

Comment: Can youshow requestPermission method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think problem is that you ask for two location permissions, you should ask only for fine location which will work for both coarse and fine.

Comment: My computer is off now. Will try this latter.

Comment: I could not wait. Yes, that was the problem. Thx

Comment: But sometimes you need permissions that are mutually exclusive.  For that, look for answer by Vitor Hugo Schwaab

Answer (score 13):

So, I can't see your `requestPermission()` method from here, but you shouldn't send multiple permission requests in the same time.

You should make ONE request with ALL the permissions.

Kotlin:

```
val permissionsCode = 42
val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
if (!hasPermissions(this, permissions)) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, permissionsCode)
}
```

Java:

```
int permissionsCode = 42; 
String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};

if (!hasPermissions(this, permissions)) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, permissionsCode);
}
```

Comment: Almos the same thing I have, isn't is?

Comment: Almost. But Android will show only ONE beautiful and well animated permission dialog. I presume that's the goal. Dialog over dialog is considered a bad interface practice.

Comment: 1 At time, but will have like a arrow to the next. But i am not displaying a Dialog over other. Or I am, and i can't see it done?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else stumbling upon this issue..You need to request permissions serially,like this:

```
onRequestPermissionResult(){
case permission1:
 if (permission1.aquired()){
....//do what you do
 requestPermission2();
 }
 case permission2:
 if (permission2.aquired()){
....//do what you do
 requestPermission3();
 }

}
```

Comment: Yep - if your code can't be arranged to ask for all permissions in one call, then you have to write a bunch of ugly code to serialize your permission requests, so that there is only one outstanding call at a time.(It would be much better if Android took care of this, rather than each application having to reinvent the wheel.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, because I was calling the function that request permissions in the `onCreate` **AND** in the `onResume`. I thing it created two instance of permissions request, and Android system does not want that.

Then, you should remove the permissions request from your `onResume` (or from any other function that would run at the same time than your Activity `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be reproduce if you are trying to get the permission in a loop -

```
do {
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions...
}while(some_condition)
```

In this case if condition is failed it may again request the same. I was able to reproduce this issue with same set of instruction.

Comment: Why should you ever want to do this?! Doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

My code for check permissions for acess camera and files.

```
protected void checkPermission(){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            // Do something, when permissions not granted
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    context,
                    new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                    },
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE
            );

        }else {
            return;
        }
    }
```

For results e manage this :

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (
                        (grantResults.length > 0) &&
                                (grantResults[0]
                                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                                )
                ) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    // permission was not granted
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                            context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                            context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                            context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                        // user denied , but not permanently
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_receipt);
                        builder.setMessage("Ops... preciso da sua permissão para incluir sua foto.");
                        builder.setTitle("Atenção");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                context,
                                new String[]{
                                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                                },
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE
                        ));
                        builder.setNeutralButton("Cancelar", null);
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    } else {
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "You denied permission.\n" +
                                "Em Configurações vá em > Permissões > E ative as permissões", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Configurações", view -> startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + <**********yourpackagename*************> ))));
                        View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                        TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
                        textView.setMaxLines(5);  //Or as much as you need
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

just add the permission in the manifest file and refresh the project

add this code in manifest XML File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION/>
```